# Error to send variable using ajax-php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I try make a login using ajax, but when sending the variables to a php file arriv empty..

ajax:

```
  function enviar()
  {
    var ced=$("#cedula").val();
    var con=$("#contraseña").val();
    $.ajax({
      async:true,
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "html",
      contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      url:"sesion/index.php",
      data:{"cedula": ced,"contraseña": con},
      beforeSend:inicioEnvio,
      success:llegada,
      error:problemas
    }); 
      return false;
  }
```

php code:

```
 $operaciones=new operaciones();
    $operaciones->conexion();
    if($operaciones->verificar_login('usuario','USU_Cedula',
       'USU_Contraseña',$_POST['cedula'],
        $_POST['contraseña'], $result)== 1){codigo}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, try the following code... it should give you a dump off everything sent..

```
<?php
  echo "Request:<br /> ", print_r($_REQUEST,true), "<br />";
  echo "Get:<br /> ", print_r($_GET,true), "<br />";
  echo "Post:<br /> ", print_r($_POST,true), "<br />";
?>
```

Otherwise, the js looks fine at a glance. i would suggest the POST method of jquery though.

```
$.post( "sesion/index.php", { "cedula": ced,"contraseña": con }).done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

Using post saves having to deal with some of the finer settings and should work in general use. PHP seems to play nicely with it as well..

The before event can be just a call in front of the post command and there is a error function as well that can be used.

**EDIT**

Sorry, miss read it i think.
By the looks of it, your not getting a value from your js vars..

Try doing an alert straight after you obtain their value and try switching them in the post... try sending test strings to your PHP.

```
var ced=$("#cedula").val();
var con=$("#contraseña").val();
alert(ced);
alert(con);

/* Try this in your post */
data:{"cedula": "test1","contraseña": "test2"},
```

Comment: See the variables arriv empty !!
Request:<br /> Array ( [cedula] => [contraseña] => ) <br />Get:<br /> Array ( ) <br />Post:<br /> Array ( [cedula] => [contraseña] => ) <br />

Comment: Then if must be that $("#cedula").val() is empty.... Replace { "cedula": ced,"contraseña": con }  ...... with { "cedula": "test1","contraseña": "test2" } --- See Edit

Comment: Once you try the above changes, you should get an idea if its the input elements causing the issues or something to do with the post. If you dont receive the post variables... are you sure its hitting the right page or your getting a print out on the right moment of the post.

Comment: I checked, the problem is in php,here: if($operaciones->verificar_login('usuario','USU_Cedula','USU_Contraseña',$_POST['cedula'],$_POST['contraseña'], $result)== 1)

Comment: So you where modifying the POST variables in PHP ? If it was your code in PHP, then that means it still did receive the POST variables but you where doing a print_r() after your code instead of the top of the page?

Comment: haha it works, but now presents this error : <b>Warning</b>: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in 

this code was used before so i don't know why presents that error,if you can help me I leave the code in response to my question to you see it better

Answer (score 0):

```
function verificar_login($tabla,$cedula_tab,$contra_tab,$txtCedula,$contraseña,&$result)
{
    $sql = "SELECT *FROM $tabla WHERE $cedula_tab = '$txtCedula' and $contra_tab = '$contraseña'
    and USU_Estado=1";
    $rec = mysql_query($sql);
    $count = 0; 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rec))
    {
        $count++;
        $result = $row;
    }   
    if($count == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: knowing psql more so, i would say that  ... USU_Estado=1 .... is not valid.. use double quotes around "USU_Estado" as it contains uppercase letters. Your getting that error because you dont have a valid SQL query / syntax.. Double check your statement.

Comment: In the way of stack overflow, if your original question gets an answer. Accept that one and any new questions start as new questions. But something like your mysql one is an easy error that can be resolved using google and that will end up pointing you back to a answer here on stackoverflow.

Comment: yeah finally works, was a problem with the letter "Ñ" I forgot use UTF-8 haha thanks for your help.